# OS X: suricata: ./configure --enable-nfqueue error

Tags: macos, suricata

I am trying to configure suricata with nfqueue on mac OS X Yosemite. When I run configure the process reports that several required items are present, but that these cannot be compile. It finally aborts with "error: pcre.h not found ...".

The full configure output is below:

```
sudo ./configure --enable-nfqueue
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... no
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.3.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.21... yes
checking gcc version... 4.2.1
checking for gawk... (cached) awk
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking for python... /usr/local/bin/python
checking for wget... /usr/local/bin/wget
checking arpa/inet.h usability... no
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: arpa/inet.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: arpa/inet.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: arpa/inet.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: arpa/inet.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: arpa/inet.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for arpa/inet.h... no
checking assert.h usability... no
checking assert.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: assert.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: assert.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: assert.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: assert.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: assert.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for assert.h... no
checking ctype.h usability... no
checking ctype.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: ctype.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: ctype.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: ctype.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: ctype.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: ctype.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for ctype.h... no
checking errno.h usability... no
checking errno.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: errno.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: errno.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: errno.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: errno.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: errno.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for errno.h... no
checking fcntl.h usability... no
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for fcntl.h... no
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking getopt.h usability... no
checking getopt.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: getopt.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: getopt.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: getopt.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: getopt.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: getopt.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for getopt.h... no
checking limits.h usability... no
checking limits.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: limits.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: limits.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: limits.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: limits.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: limits.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for limits.h... no
checking netdb.h usability... no
checking netdb.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: netdb.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: netdb.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: netdb.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: netdb.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: netdb.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for netdb.h... no
checking netinet/in.h usability... no
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: netinet/in.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: netinet/in.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: netinet/in.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: netinet/in.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: netinet/in.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for netinet/in.h... no
checking poll.h usability... no
checking poll.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: poll.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: poll.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: poll.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: poll.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: poll.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for poll.h... no
checking sched.h usability... no
checking sched.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: sched.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: sched.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: sched.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: sched.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: sched.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for sched.h... no
checking signal.h usability... no
checking signal.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: signal.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: signal.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: signal.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: signal.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: signal.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for signal.h... no
checking stdarg.h usability... no
checking stdarg.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: stdarg.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: stdarg.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: stdarg.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: stdarg.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: stdarg.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for stdarg.h... no
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking stdio.h usability... no
checking stdio.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: stdio.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: stdio.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: stdio.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: stdio.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: stdio.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for stdio.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... no
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: sys/ioctl.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: sys/ioctl.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: sys/ioctl.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: sys/ioctl.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: sys/ioctl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for sys/ioctl.h... no
checking syslog.h usability... no
checking syslog.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: syslog.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: syslog.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: syslog.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: syslog.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: syslog.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for syslog.h... no
checking sys/prctl.h usability... no
checking sys/prctl.h presence... no
checking for sys/prctl.h... no
checking sys/socket.h usability... no -->

checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: sys/socket.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: sys/socket.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: sys/socket.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: sys/socket.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: sys/socket.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/syscall.h usability... no
checking sys/syscall.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: sys/syscall.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: sys/syscall.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: sys/syscall.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: sys/syscall.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: sys/syscall.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for sys/syscall.h... no
checking sys/time.h usability... no
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: sys/time.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: sys/time.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: sys/time.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: sys/time.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: sys/time.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for sys/time.h... no
checking time.h usability... no
checking time.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: time.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: time.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: time.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: time.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: time.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for time.h... no
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... (cached) no
checking linux/if_ether.h usability... no
checking linux/if_ether.h presence... no
checking for linux/if_ether.h... no
checking linux/if_packet.h usability... no
checking linux/if_packet.h presence... no
checking for linux/if_packet.h... no
checking linux/filter.h usability... no
checking linux/filter.h presence... no
checking for linux/filter.h... no
checking linux/ethtool.h usability... no
checking linux/ethtool.h presence... no
checking for linux/ethtool.h... no
checking linux/sockios.h usability... no
checking linux/sockios.h presence... no
checking for linux/sockios.h... no
checking for sys/socket.h... (cached) no
checking for net/if.h... no
checking for sys/mman.h... no
checking for linux/if_arp.h... no
checking for windows.h... no
checking for winsock2.h... no
checking for ws2tcpip.h... no
checking for w32api/wtypes.h... no
checking for w32api/winbase.h... no
checking for inline... no
checking for pid_t... no
checking for size_t... no
checking for int32_t... no
checking for uint16_t... no
checking for uint32_t... no
checking for uint64_t... no
checking for uint8_t... no
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... no
checking for _Bool... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... no
checking for gettimeofday... no
checking for memset... no
checking for strcasecmp... no
checking for strchr... no
checking for strdup... no
checking for strerror... no
checking for strncasecmp... no
checking for strtol... no
checking for strtoul... no
checking for memchr... no
checking for memrchr... no
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for strlcat... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... unknown
checking for _LARGE_FILES value needed for large files... unknown
checking host os... -n installation for x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 OS... 
ok
checking for thread local storage __thread support... no
checking checking if gcc supports -march=native... no
checking for spatch... no
   Warning! spatch not found, you will not be 
   able to run code checking with coccinelle  
   get it from http://coccinelle.lip6.fr      
   or install from your distribution          
checking for Mpipe... no
checking pcre.h usability... no
checking pcre.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: pcre.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: pcre.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for pcre.h... no
configure: error: pcre.h not found ...
```

I've got pcre installed from [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

I've tried this:

```
sudo CC=llvm-gcc ./configure --enable-nfqueue
```

and got:

```
...
checking for json_dump_callback in -ljansson... yes
checking for nfnl_fd in -lnfnetlink... no

   ERROR!  nfnetlink library not found, go get it
   from www.netfilter.org.
   we automatically append libnetfilter_queue/ when searching
   for headers etc. when the --with-libnfnetlink-inlcudes directive
   is used

checking libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h usability... no
checking libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h presence... no
checking for libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h... no
configure: error: libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h not found ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well, I have no clue what should I try. What are your suggestions? what could be a problem? I've got pcre installed from homebrew.

Comment: I've tried to add --disable-gccmarch-native to configuration command and still get the same.

Comment: 1) Is libnetfilter installed? (ii not, install it first)
2) What does `locate nfnetlink.h` report? (your output now says it does not find it. If it is installed but not found then it might not look in the right places)
3) Does it work if you temporarily remove the `--enable-nfqueue` part?

Comment: 1) I haven't found the `libnetfilter` for mac (may be it supposed to be a part of some package from homebrew like `libnet` or `libdnet` which are already installed as dependancies for suricata)... I have no idea what is it... 2) `locate nfnetlink.h` shows nothing - seems like it's not installed. Homebrew doesn't have such packages like nfnetlink or libnetfilter((( 3) if I remove `--enable-nfqueue` it works but the reason I ask all that - because I need suricata to be installed with nfqueue support (((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like configuring suricata with `--enable-nfqueue` is impossible on OS X. Please correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I have no OS X to test with, but ...

Focusing on the error message and googling on "suricata OSX" leads me to the following webpage: https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Mac_OS_X_106x

Quoting part of that:

*Recent versions of OS X use clang which does not support the CFLAG -fno-tree-pre, resulting in the following warnings:*

```
configure: WARNING: pcre.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled" 
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for pcre.h... no
```

*Replace clang with llvm-gcc to fix this problem:*

```
CC=llvm-gcc ./configure ...
```

Ok, so that worked for the first problem. Suricata can now be succesfully  compiled.

Now you have run into a second problem: You are trying to build a program which used netfilter, but you do not have that package installed. You either need to:

1. find (and install) an OS X version of that,
2. find and configure a replacement (perhaps something which is already in OS X itself?), or
3. you need to compile it yourself.
4. or you need to compile it without.

However this is no longer the original question.

Comment: I've tried this, but it didn't work. I've edited my question above... check the log